# How to remove or update virtual directory in IIS 7 with C# code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, iis-7, iis-7.5

I can add a virtual directory with the following code
using Microsoft.web.administration;

app.VirtualDirectories.Add("/vDir", "C:\inetpub\Ztet");

and the code works but how can i update this or change this or delete this with code? lets say i wanted to change the virtual directory name or path?

I tried

app.virtualDirectories.Remove( ?? ===Fail

also Tried to overwrite with
app.VirtualDirectories.Add("/vDir", "C:\inetpub\Xtet");   //with different path but fails once it already exists

Any tips will be appriciated
also any idea on how to assign or change associated username and password for the virtual direcotry?

Comment: solved the username and password issue with VirtualDirectory object virtDir.username ="String"; virtDir.password ="******"; worked still stuck on how to remove, rename or update existing virtual directories

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few samples:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateApp();

        RenameApp();

        EditApp();

        DeleteApp();
    }

    private static void EditApp()
    {
        using (ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager())
        {
            Application app = mgr.Sites["Default Web Site"].Applications["/TestAppNew"];
            VirtualDirectory vdir = app.VirtualDirectories["/"];
            vdir.UserName = "SomeUser";
            vdir.Password = "SomePassword";
            mgr.CommitChanges();
        }
    }

    private static void DeleteApp()
    {
        using (ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager())
        {

            Application app = mgr.Sites["Default Web Site"].Applications["/TestAppNew"];
            mgr.Sites["Default Web Site"].Applications.Remove(app);
            mgr.CommitChanges();
        }
    }

    private static void RenameApp()
    {
        using (ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager())
        {

            Application app = mgr.Sites["Default Web Site"].Applications["/TestApp"];
            app.Path = "/TestAppNew";

            mgr.CommitChanges();
        }
    }

    private static void CreateApp()
    {
        using (ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager())
        {

            mgr.Sites["Default Web Site"].Applications.Add("/TestApp", @"c:\inetpub\wwwroot");

            mgr.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This did the tricks Thank you so much I was stuck on the updating virtual direcotory